# Cannot run npm commands due to sh: 1: webpack: not found error; same exact codebase runs commands fine elsewhere

Tags: npm, webpack, nvm

I'm having a very strange issue with nvm, npm and webpack.

We have a webpack file with a `npm run publish` command. I have 4 stacks setup locally on the same code repository. In 3 of the stacks, I can `npm run publish` without an issue. However, in the 4th stack I always get a `sh: 1: webpack: not found` error when I run the command. The worrisome bit, is the codebases are identical. I've ran diffs, altered permissions, ran `npm rebuild`, re-ran `npm install` and `nvm use`. I've removed the `node_modules` directory and ran an `npm install`. No matter what I do, I get the same error.

Here is the verbose error with a few local names blocked out:

```
21 timing command:run-script Completed in 25ms
22 verbose stack Error: command failed
22 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.proc.on (/home/<usr>/.nvm/versions/node/v11.14.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/index.js:64:27)
22 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:193:13)
22 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:999:16)
22 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:266:5)
```

Any help is very much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Do you have webpack in your package.json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving it by copying over the `node_modules` directory from one of the working codebases. Not entirely sure what the problem was though.